# Gmail - how to get all my email address from mailbox into contacts?

Tags: email, backup, gmail, import, google-contacts

In my Gmail i have total 3000 Emails (inbox, sent item, important etc). But all 3000 Email address is not in my Google Contact list.

how can i export email address from the Gmail inbox/sent item/important into Google Contact list?

Comment: This probably isn't something you want to do on your Android. See: [Get e-mail addresses from Gmail messages received](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/9813)